# I got Token Signature could not be verified with external API and internal requests in my app

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, axios, vuex, jwt

In Laravel 5.8 / vuejs / vuex / mysql app I use jwt-auth and when I login into 
the system (standard auth with mysql users table) I use method :

```
export function setAuthorizationToken(token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`
}
```

and it worked ok.

Next I need to remade SignUp/SignIn to use external API for SignUp/SignIn operations.
So my app needs to make SignUp/SignIn  with external API , but also I have requests for controls of my app to read/write data from/to my sql.

SignIn request to external API returns token only and I keep it in the setAuthorizationToken method above.
Next I need to read user details from this external API and to save it in vuex store. I make it and it works ok, but the problem is that 
my next axios request to my control to read data from db triggers error:

> Token Signature could not be verified.

I understand why but it there is a way to fix it? 
Is it possible to replace Bearer for axios when I need it?
Maybe some replacement of axios to to use both  axios and replacement ?

```
"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0",


"vue": "^2.5.17",
"axios": "^0.18",
"vuex": "^3.1.0"
```

Thanks!

**MODIFIED** :

Searching for a decision on login I keen token I got in cookie 'external_token'

```
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Auth-Token': getCookie('external_token'),
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
    };
    axios.get(user_details_url, headers)
        .then((response) => {
        ...
        })
        .catch((err) =>{
        })
```

But I got error in console :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://remoteserver.com/api/user' from origin 'http://local-wiznext.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

where remoteserver.com is remote server with API and http://local-wiznext.com is my local server I am developing at

Searching for a decision I found several additive parameters to add to header of my axios request :

```
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Auth-Token': getCookie('external_token'),
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
        'crossDomain': true,
       'dataType': 'jsonp',
    };
    // axios.get(url, {headers})
```

But I got the same CORS error.
If there is a way to fix this error and run request?

**MODIFIED** # 2 :

Admin of my sever used this option 
https://support.cloudways.com/enable-cors-headers/
and enabled CORS headers
and restartes debian, but I still get CORS errors.
Any ideas how to fix problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can understand from the question is you have an external API and internal API which uses different tokens. So instead of setting the token after SignUp/SignIn, you can set the token in the cookie after SignUp/SignIn. For external token you can name it as `external_token` and for internal you can set as `token` in the cookie. Now whenever you will trigger an axios call, you know in advance whether the API is external or internal and based on that you will set the token only for that API call and not set the default Authorization  header.

Comment: Could you please give a link how to  the token in the cookie after SignUp/SignIn ? Some libs/pure JS must be used here ?

Comment: Just search for storing the token in the cookie. You don't have to use any JS library here.

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED block

Comment: Pls, look at MODIFIED # 2

Comment: Sorry, no desicion ?